# Filter Certificates Get-Date results AddDays NotAfter

Tags: powershell

I'm building a little script to get all certificates, but I only want results for certificates which expires within 60 days. Here's what I got so far:

```
Get-ChildItem cert:\ -Recurse | Select @{Name='FriendlyName';Expression={$_.FriendlyName}},
       @{Name='NotAfter';Expression={Get-Date -Date $_.NotAfter -Uformat "%d-%m-%Y"}},
       @{Name='Thumbprint';Expression={$_.Thumbprint}},
       @{Name='DnsNameList';Expression={$_.DnsNameList}},
       @{Name='issuer';Expression={(($_.Issuer).Split("=")[1]).Split(",")[0]}}
```

This script returns all certificates in a nice sorted list. Like I said, I want to filter those results for expiring within 60 days. So I tried to filter the results like this:

```
| where {$_.NotAfter -lt ([datetime]::now).AddDays(60)}
```

But I wouldn't be here if this would work :)
Where do I go wrong?

I know I can do this by doing:

```
Get-ChildItem cert:\ -Recurse | Select-Object Issuer, DnsNameList, FriendlyName, Thumbprint, NotAfter | where {$_.NotAfter -lt ([datetime]::now).AddDays(60)}
```

But I need the `Select @{Name='FriendlyName etc` for a third party app which is expecting this format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to compare string created with:

```
@{Name='NotAfter';Expression={Get-Date -Date $_.NotAfter -Uformat "%d-%m-%Y"}},
```

with the date, which might not work as expected. Instead, filter it first and then format as needed using `Select-Object`. Something along these lines (linebreaks added for visibility):

```
Get-ChildItem cert:\ -Recurse | `
Where-Object {$_.NotAfter -lt ([datetime]::now).AddDays(60)} | `
Select-Object @{Name='FriendlyName';Expression={$_.FriendlyName}},
       @{Name='NotAfter';Expression={Get-Date -Date $_.NotAfter -Uformat "%d-%m-%Y"}},
       @{Name='Thumbprint';Expression={$_.Thumbprint}},
       @{Name='DnsNameList';Expression={$_.DnsNameList}},
       @{Name='issuer';Expression={(($_.Issuer).Split("=")[1]).Split(",")[0]}}
```